# Google work space add on with Google apps script, How can I deploy it all staffs of mine

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace, google-workspace-add-ons

I'm a corporate systems administrator.

our company uses google-workspace, and I need to extend gmail by using google-apps-script.

Since I created a google-workspace-add-on with google-apps-script.

Coding and testing was not so hard by following this page.

https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/how-tos/testing-gsuite-addons

However, deploying is pretty confusing for me.

this add-on is only used for our company, and it includes api-key for our private service.

Then I want to avoid the add on to publicly published.

The following instruction explains to use GCP project, and then install it from administrator console.
https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/how-tos/publish-add-on-overview

I want to know

1, Is there any way to deploy my google-workspace-add-on more primitively ?

2, If I followed this instruction, is it for free or costly?(I have no knowledge of GCP billing system)

Comment: 1. What do you mean by `more primitively`? 2. Publlishing add-ons for your domain is free.

Comment: Thank  you for your answer and sorry for my misunderstanding expression.  'primitively' means that if I could install my add-on to same domain members with the way like testing add-on(from Deployment Dialogue of Apps Script Editor)

Comment: No, you have to do it via the admin panel. See [here](https://support.google.com/a/answer/172482?hl=en).